# 404 error in oracle 10g after entering credentials in windows 8.1

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Something terrible is happening in my oracle 10g application express

Just like yesterday, when today i opened oracle 10g application express, after i entered my credentials(username,password), when i pressed 'login', the browser displayed a 404 error page saying that the link does not exist.

I am completely dumbstruck over this, as i have been using it for 3 months now, and this kind of error never occured, and i am pretty sure i didn't do anything to cause it since i have only the shortcut of the browser on my desktop, so any unintentional tampering to the application is unlikely.

I have many important databases of my final year project in there, and i really want to avoid re-installation. Please someone help me with the problem...

[image 1 before login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxoYt.png)

[image 2 shows after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5fw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well so it was happening because of system trigger i definded on the database...i dropped that trigger using JDBC...but the trigger wasn't causing it because of any syntax error, it is just buggy oracle 10g.